# Java compiler or android compiler is truncating my doubles...?

Tags: java, android

So I was working on a fitness app that I have been on for quite some time. We were getting this weird defect where calories weren't increasing but distance was.. so I investigated. I started de-bugging, and saw duration was coming in as whole numbers, 0, 5.0, 2.0, etc. Yet this value was a double. The code below is part of a module, that we import as an .aar dependency via maven.

Here is the actual source code:

```
double duration = (System.currentTimeMillis() - mPreviousTimestamp) / 1000;
```

The decompiled class file, which I was de-bugging from:

```
double duration = (double)((System.currentTimeMillis() - this.mPreviousTimestamp) / 1000L);
```

Any thoughts as to, why this is happening, and a possible solution? Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 2):

The result of

```
(System.currentTimeMillis() - mPreviousTimestamp) / 1000
```

is an `int`. You have an `int` divided by an `int`. The result of that is an `int`. You then cast that `int` to a `double` via the assignment, but at that point the precision is gone.

You should do this,

```
double duration = (System.currentTimeMillis() - mPreviousTimestamp) / 1000.0;
```

By including the double (1000.0) in the calculation, it makes the result of the expression a double also.

Comment: yeah this is what I ended up doing. Rookie mistake on my part... oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Text.setText( String.format( "Value of a: %.8f", a ) );

For 8 decimal places!